# Biff exception in Java

Tags: java, excel, exception

When I tried to read an Excel file in Java it throws "biff exception".

What does this mean? I tried to Google it but wasn't able to find a proper explanation.

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream

                             at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)

                             at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)

                             at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)

                             at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)

                             at Com.Parsing.ExcelFile.excel(Extract.java:20)

                             at Com.Parsing.Extract.main(Extract.java:55)
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: If anyone wonders what BIFF means, it is the Excel file format and is an acronym of "Binary Interchange File Format".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc for [BiffException](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_3_1/docs/jxl/read/biff/BiffException.html).

*Exception thrown when reading a biff file.*

This exception has a number of messages that should provide some information about the cause:

```
excelFileNotFound        
excelFileTooBig         
expectedGlobals         
passwordProtected         
streamNotFound         
unrecognizedBiffVersion
unrecognizedOLEFile
```

**Edit:**

`unrecognizedOLEFile` seems to mean that something is [embedded in the file that cannot be read](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=687653).

Comment: The link on the last line is broken

Answer (score 5):

I also faced similar problem and was able to fix it.

I was using a .xlsx file and when I changed it to .xls file, it worked just fine. Seems JXL doesn't support .xlsx format.

Please correct me if somebody knows that it supports.

Answer (score 1):

An Excel workbook with several sheets (from BIFF5 on) is stored using the compound document file format (also known as “OLE2 storage file format” or “Microsoft Office compatible storage file format”). It contains several streams for different types of data.

A complete documentation of the format of compound document files can be found at
http://sc.openoffice.org/compdocfileformat.pdf

I think the exception mean that your parsing library can not recognise it(For example:biff5 format can not be parsed in POI and Jexcelapi).
You can check your file version be open it in Office and click 'SAVE AS',the format list in the filedialog is it's current file version.