# want to fetch the data from excel file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Data drven framework, where the values are changing for every case

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException {       
            Sheet s;
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("D:\\Nikhil\\FGX\\DataDriven.xlsx");
            Workbook W = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);

            s = W.getSheet(0);

            for(int row = 0;row <= s.getRows();row++)
            {
                String Username = s.getCell(0,row).getContents();
                System.out.println("Username" +Username);
                driver.get("http://********");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginName']")).sendKeys(Username);

                String password= s.getCell(1, row).getContents();
                System.out.println("Password "+password);

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys(password);

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div/div/div/div/fieldset/button")).click();
        }
```

Comment: giving Bliff exception

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to get the BiffException look at [Biff exception in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747665/biff-exception-in-java).

Make sure you point the correct file, sheet, cell etc. You need to fetch and iterate the excel data. I may not answered directly to your answer, but the below code might help you,

`List getData() {` **Fetch the data

```
      String path = "filepath";
      List dataList = new ArrayList();
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      try { 
          fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("TestData");
          java.util.Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

          while (rows.hasNext()) {
              XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) rows.next());
              // int r=row.getRowNum();
              java.util.Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
              int i = 0;
              String[] testData= new String[3];
              while (cells.hasNext()) {

                  XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                  String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                  if (!value.equals(null)) {
                       testData [i] = value;
                       i++;
                  }
              }
              dataList.add(testData);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return dataList;
}



public Object[][] data() { **Store the data in desired format

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List dataList= getData();
    Object a[][]=new Object[dataList.size()][2];
    for(int i=1;i<dataList.size();i++){
        String[] test=(String[]) dataList.get(i);
        String username = test[0];
        String password=test[1];
        a[i][0]=username;
        a[i][1]=password;
    }
    return a;
```